# how can i do to create pivot table from database in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, date, pivot-table

I have one mounthly database like this

[image]

I want to count medianumber and group them into one hour period and create a pivot table like this

[image]

how can i do?

Comment: Use a time and calendar table to create **normalised** data, and then use your presentation layer to create the Pivot Table/Matrix. SSRS would be a good candidate. Otherwise you could only achieve this with Dynamic SQL; and that's unlikely to be easy for someone who is only starting with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I try this

select *
  from (select substring (charindex (Date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24'), 1, 16) as dy
          from dataTable) as TT
          pivot 
          (count (Date)
                             for dy
                             in ([01.10.2018 00],
                                 [01.10.2018 01],
                                 [01.10.2018 02],
                                 [01.10.2018 03],
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
                                 [01.10.2018 22],
                                 [01.10.2018 23])) piv

but i can't solve  *(Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name 'Date'.)*